# How is 'storage space used' calculated in Astra?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-astra

I understand that a user is charged for 'storage space used' based on the monthly max usage, but how do things like a Replication Factor of 3 and the way compaction is configured play into the monthly max utilization of storage space?

Is a user charged for all live sstables?

Is it possible to misconfigure compaction and end up with larger than normal disk utilization?

Answer (score 2):

[DataStax Astra DB](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-astra) charges external users for only one copy of the data but, internally replicates it for high availability. Since Astra DB is a serverless database-as-a-service (DBaaS) option, users will only be able to set the [time to live property](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/plan/planning.html#_astra_db_database_guardrails_and_limits) at the table-level and no other option is available [to misconfigure]. See [pricing](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-astra/pricing#metering-explained) details and [this documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/manage/org/manage-billing.html#_units_of_measure) for other details.